# How to express the notion of a vector, where every element inside is matrix?

Tags: self-study, notation, tensor

I met a question when I tried to express a **vector**, where every element inside is a **matrix**. We know the notion usually works like this:

- scalar: $a$
- vector: $\boldsymbol{a}$
- matrix: $\boldsymbol A$
- vector (elements inside are vector): $\boldsymbol{A} = [\boldsymbol{a}_1, \boldsymbol{a} _2, \boldsymbol{a} _3]$

What if I want to express a vector (or tensor) where the elements are matrices, like the following:

- vector (elements inside are vector): $? = [\boldsymbol{A}_1, \boldsymbol{A} _2, \boldsymbol{A} _3]$

Should I still use $\boldsymbol A$, Or is there a formal expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is about conventions, and it will differ from field to field. You should use the conventions of your field.

Otherwise, the standard ISO 80000-2 identifies notation for scalars, vectors, matrices, tensors, and more. *Symbols for tensors are in sans-serif bold italic.* The [isomath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/isomath) package implements this in LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Arya! I checked the materials you mentioned, and it seems the symbols of matrix(2-15.1) and tensor(2-17.19) are the same: both are sans-serif bold italic with a capital case. Thanks again!

Comment: The matrix notation has serifs. The tensors don’t.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that difference! Thank you so much for pointing it out. Problem solved!

Comment: +1 for isomath, great little package